# Split up @ArticleStartDate Month and Day to resemble a calendar page

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, date-time, item-styles

Using SharePoint 2013, I have a custom ItemStyle.xsl file where I have the following code:

```
<div class="articledate">
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'MMM d')"/>
</div>
```

It currently shows up as August 18 like this.

[image]

What I would like to do is split it up in two - the Month and Day would be separate so I could style them to look like this icon for example.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'MMM')"/><br/><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'd')"/>`

Comment: It worked when I used 'dd' instead of 'd'.  It would use the whole date instead.  Weird.

Comment: Cool. You can post your solution as answer. It will help others who are looking for similar solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the code below using month, day 01-31, and abbreviated name of the day:

```
<div class="articledate">
<div class="ArticleMonth">
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'MMM')"/>
</div>
<div class="ArticleDay">
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'dd')"/>
</div>
<div class="ArticleDDay">
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@ArticleStartDate), 1033, 'ddd')"/>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]